# async.forEachSeries followed by array.forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous

Say I have a function in which async.forEachSeries is preceeded by array.forEach(). What will be the order of execution ? Does async.forEachSeries execute after array.forEach() finishes ?

```
function(){
  array.forEach(){ push into array something}
  async.forEachSeries(array){
    request.get(array.element)
  }

}
```

I have the following code which does not always run as intended,it runs most of the time but sometimes at lines like sresult.data.push(...) it says that sresult.data is undefined. The most probable reason that I could understand is that the code is not running in sequence and hence, sresult.data is not defined when it runs. Can anyone help with this ?

```
 function (callback) {
                request.get(config.url.sectionMaster + "?parentSectionCode=" + sectionCode, function (err, result) {
                    // console.log(1)
                    // console.log(result)
                    if (err) { return next(err) }
                    if (result != undefined) {
                        result = JSON.parse(result.body)
                        let firstHeading = result.data
                        if (firstHeading != null) {
                            firstHeading.forEach(element => {
                                firstHeadingArray.push({
                                    "entityId": entityId,
                                    "finYear": finYear,
                                    "sectionCodeHead": sectionCode,
                                    "unit": unit,
                                    "sectionCodeDet": element.sectionCode,
                                    "sectionName": element.sectionName,
                                    "asOfDate": "",
                                    "childAmount": "0.00",
                                    "parentAmount": "0.00",
                                    "manualEntry": 0,
                                    "dispOrder": element.dispOrder,
                                    "AppStatus": "",
                                    "Status": "",
                                    "WF_SERIALNUMBER": "",
                                    "WF_ACTION": "",
                                    "leafNode": "",
                                    "data": []
                                })
                            });
                        } else {
                            return next("No first heading")
                        }
                    } else {
                        return next("Parent section code undefined.")
                    }
                    async.forEachSeries(firstHeadingArray, function (felement, fcallback) {
                        console.log(2)
                        request.get(config.url.sectionMaster + "?parentSectionCode=" + felement.sectionCodeDet, function (err, fresult) {
                            if (err) { return next(err) }
                            if (fresult != undefined) {
                                fresult = JSON.parse(fresult.body)
                                sheading = fresult.data
                                if (sheading != null) {
                                    sheading.forEach(function (element) {
                                        if (felement.data != undefined) {
                                            felement.data.push({
                                                "entityId": entityId,
                                                "finYear": finYear,
                                                "sectionCodeHead": sectionCode,
                                                "unit": unit,
                                                "sectionCodeDet": element.sectionCode,
                                                "sectionName": element.sectionName,
                                                "asOfDate": "",
                                                "childAmount": "0.00",
                                                "parentAmount": "0.00",
                                                "manualEntry": 0,
                                                "dispOrder": element.dispOrder,
                                                "AppStatus": "",
                                                "Status": "",
                                                "WF_SERIALNUMBER": "",
                                                "WF_ACTION": "",
                                                "leafNode": "",
                                                "data": []
                                            })
                                        } else {
                                            console.log(felement)
                                            return next({ message: "Error 1" })
                                        }
                                    })

                                } else { }
                            } else { return next({ message: "Parent section code undefined." }) }
                            async.forEachSeries(felement.data, function (selement, scallback) {
                                console.log(3)
                                request.get(config.url.sectionMaster + "?parentSectionCode=" + selement.sectionCodeDet, function (err1, sresult) {
                                    if (err1) { return next(err1) }
                                    if (sresult != undefined) {
                                        sresult = JSON.parse(sresult.body)
                                        theading = sresult.data
                                        if (theading != null) {
                                            theading.forEach(telement => {
                                                selement.data.push({
                                                    "entityId": entityId,
                                                    "finYear": finYear,
                                                    "sectionCodeHead": sectionCode,
                                                    "unit": unit,
                                                    "sectionCodeDet": telement.sectionCode,
                                                    "sectionName": telement.sectionName,
                                                    "asOfDate": "",
                                                    "childAmount": "0.00",
                                                    "parentAmount": "0.00",
                                                    "manualEntry": 0,
                                                    "dispOrder": telement.dispOrder,
                                                    "AppStatus": "",
                                                    "Status": "",
                                                    "WF_SERIALNUMBER": "",
                                                    "WF_ACTION": "",
                                                    "leafNode": "",
                                                    "data": []
                                                })
                                            });
                                        } else { }
                                    } else { return next({ message: "Parent section code undefined." }) }
                                    async.forEachSeries(selement.data, function (belement, abc) {
                                        console.log(4)
                                        request.get(config.url.sectionMaster + "?parentSectionCode=" + belement.sectionCodeDet, function (err2, bresult) {
                                            if (err2) { return next(err2) }
                                            if (bresult != undefined) {
                                                bresult = JSON.parse(bresult.body)
                                                bheading = bresult.data
                                                if (bheading != null) {
                                                    bheading.forEach(helement => {
                                                        belement.data.push({
                                                            "entityId": entityId,
                                                            "finYear": finYear,
                                                            "sectionCodeHead": sectionCode,
                                                            "unit": unit,
                                                            "sectionCodeDet": helement.sectionCode,
                                                            "sectionName": helement.sectionName,
                                                            "asOfDate": "",
                                                            "childAmount": "0.00",
                                                            "parentAmount": "0.00",
                                                            "manualEntry": 0,
                                                            "dispOrder": helement.dispOrder,
                                                            "AppStatus": "",
                                                            "Status": "",
                                                            "WF_SERIALNUMBER": "",
                                                            "WF_ACTION": "",
                                                            "leafNode": "",
                                                            "data": []
                                                        })
                                                    })
                                                }
                                            }

                                            abc()
                                        })
                                    }, function (err) {
                                        scallback()
                                    })

                                })
                            }, function (err) {
                                fcallback()
                            })
                        })
                    }, function (err) {
                        callback(err, firstHeadingArray)
                    })
                })
            }
```

Comment: Is `ForEach` a custom function? (the `Array.prototype` function name is `forEach`) If that's the `Array.prototype` function, then it's 100% synchronous (unless there are asynchronous operations inside the `forEach`)

Comment: Sorry edited it, its the Array.prototype function. So does the async.forEachSeries block execute after my array.forEach finishes ?

Comment: Yes, just like everything in Javascript - if statement/expression A is above statement B on the same block, then (the synchronous code of) A will execute before (the synchronous code of) B

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but the code that i just added sometimes doesn't run as intended(sometimes sresult.data comes as undefined). I suspect it's because my code is not running in sequence